# Finish My Sentence and Finish My Journey

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, quote

IsteamboatbruntfootballdomedicalslamsadultssolemnlysoonertextwiringswearscenesremindliftsthatwoodenrespectswaspIboughtlinerblastwilldullelaborateyieldsfaithfullyspelldrivelevelexecutestowawakecurvythewalledjustpoppyofficespeededeachorientationofbattleactorsvenuespresidentoperatunnelchairofstowawakecurvytheimprintperfectedthyroidunitedmedicalslamsadultsstatescivilsheepstickandnapsclottingplushwillfeedsbountydealtolobsterreasoncapturesthelibrariesmarbletryingbestnuzzledcafeteriacuddledof
sliceslikelyexactmy

What's my name? What did I say? Where did I end up?

Answer (score 7):

We can split the text into the following words:

> I steamboat brunt football do medical slams adults solemnly sooner text wiring swear scenes remind lifts that wooden respects wasp I bought liner blast will dull elaborate yields faithfully spell drive level execute stow awake curvy the walled just poppy office speeded each orientation of battle actors venues president opera tunnel chair of stow awake curvy the imprint perfected thyroid united medical slams adults states civil sheep stick and naps clotting plush will feeds bounty deal to lobster reason captures the libraries marble trying best nuzzled cafeteria cuddled of slices likely exact my

Where I noticed that there are words repeating, such as:

> medical slams adults

And:

> Stow awake (as @Techidiot figured out)

**Updated** answer:
As Wu33o figured out, here is what happens to the text if you take

> The first word and each third word after:
>  **I** steamboat brunt football **do** medical slams adults **solemnly** sooner text wiring **swear** scenes remind lifts **that** wooden respects wasp **I** bought liner blast **will** dull elaborate yields **faithfully** spell drive level **execute** stow awake curvy **the** walled just poppy **office** speeded each orientation **of** battle actors venues **president** opera tunnel chair **of** stow awake curvy **the** imprint perfected thyroid **united** medical slams adults **states** civil sheep stick **and** naps clotting plush **will** feeds bounty deal **to** lobster reason captures **the** libraries marble trying **best** nuzzled cafeteria cuddled **of** slices likely exact **my**

I guess this makes you

> One of the Presidents of the United States. That means, you did end up at the White House.

**Update 2**
You might be:

> Barack Obama

Explanation:

> You did write some keywords that belong to Obama. Libraries, Opera (Referring to the conversation with Oprah Winfrey last December) and at last the letters of OBAMA can be found in STEAMBOAT.

Comment: **stow awake** is repeated as well. Just split *execute stow awake* in your answer.

Comment: @Techidiot Thanks for your addition. I updated my answer.

Comment: I think steamboat is supposed to be one word, to fit the pattern.

Comment: All of the words are useful, not just some of them

Comment: Besides the fact that I did not write down all words, is the answer right? If yes, perhaps people can fill in as I am not familiar with presidents of the White House..

Comment: The answer is correct :)  but the explanation isn't - I'll let other people have a go at getting the explanation for a bit

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> Donald Trump

You said:

> I do solemnly swear that I will faithfully execute the office of President of the United States, and will to the best of my

You ended up:

> In the White House

Explanation:

> Divide the text into words, take the first word, skip 3 words, take the next word, skip 3 words, etc. See @Mike Limburg's answer for the text divided into words.

Comment: Nearly...the quote is (part of) the presidential oath, but you have the wrong president